# Java compiler error with generics

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

I'm getting a compiler error with this code:

```
Map<String, String[]> myMap;

void set(Map<String, Object> foo) { }

set(myMap); // generates error

Error: "The method set(Map<String,Object>) in the type XXX is not applicable for the arguments (Map<String,String[]>)"
```

This makes no sense to me, because String[] is in fact an Object, and is entirely compatible with the parameter in set().

This error did not show up in my code until I upgraded from JDK 1.6 to 1.7. I do not see a switch in Eclipse to turn it off. How do I get this code to compile?

Edit:

It does compile if I use an intermediate variable, and drop the generics:

```
Map anotherMap = myMap;
set(anotherMap);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generics inheritance is different from our regular understanding of OO inheritance. Please read this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html).

To make your code compile, you may need to change your method syntax like below:

```
void set(Map<String, ?> foo) { }
```

EDIT: As dasblinkenlight commented, if you have any plans to do modifications to the Map inside the set method, it won't work unless you have concrete type defined.

Comment: The `Map<String,?>` will not *work*, but merely *compile*. As soon as the method tries to `put` anything into `foo`, the compiler will complain.

Comment: To round things out, think what would happen if that *did* work. Within the `set` method, you have a `Map<String, Object>` so you happily call `map.put("foo", new SomeObject())`. Now `myMap`, though it's typed such that the values are of `String[]`, has a value of `SomeObject`.

Answer (score 1):

Although `String[]` is in fact an `Object`, that is not the same as saying that `Map<String,String[]>` is in fact a `Map<String,Object>`: the *covariance* of generics is not there.

Changing the declaration

```
void set(Map<String,Object> foo) { }
```

to one with wildcard

```
void set(Map<String,?> foo) { }
```

will make your code compile, and attempts to get things from the `foo` map will work:

```
Object blah = foo.get("key");
```

However, attempts to add things to the map would fail:

<strike>Object blah = foo.put("key");</strike>

Since putting things in the map appears to be the goal of your method (after all, there must be a reason why you called it `set`) you wouldn't be able to make it work without specifying the exact type.

Answer (score 0):

When you use type parameters in generics, inheritence does not work the same way.

Here's an over-simplified general rule of thumb:

*The stuff inside the `<>`s must match exactly when declaring and initializing generic objects.*

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, Eclipse did compiled your code because of it's compiler bug.

You'll need to change signature of `set` to `set(Map<String, ?>)` to make it compile.

It compiles in 2nd case with a warning, isn't it? It's because you use raw Map (w/o generics) to circumvent type-safety check.